# Display file Properties > Security > Edit (permissions)

Tags: c#, shellexecute

I successfully implemented the solution from  [How does one invoke the Windows Permissions dialog programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035464/how-does-one-invoke-the-windows-permissions-dialog-programmatically) and related:  [How to display file properties dialog security tab from c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30603139/how-to-display-file-properties-dialog-security-tab-from-c-sharp).

```
    public static bool ShowFileProperties(string Filename)
    {
        SHELLEXECUTEINFO info = new SHELLEXECUTEINFO();
        info.cbSize = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(info);
        info.lpVerb = "properties";
        info.lpFile = Filename;
        info.lpParameters = "Security";
        info.nShow = SW_SHOW;
        info.fMask = SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST;
        return ShellExecuteEx(ref info);
    }
```

However, I would like to get to the Permissions window as you would with the Edit.. button from that dialogue.

[image]
[image: ![enter image description here]

Any ideas?

Comment: There is no Edit.. button in that dialog.

Comment: Yes, I added another image.  The second one is the result of clicking Edit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can click the button "Edit..." programmatically:

Edited example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41961339/click-a-button-programmatically-c-sharp), matching to the window title seen in your Screenshot:

```
private void clickEdit()
{
    // Look for a top-level window/application called "SupportAssist Properties"
    var root = AutomationElement.RootElement;
    var condition1 = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "SupportAssist Properties");

    var treeWalker = new TreeWalker(condition1);
    AutomationElement element = treeWalker.GetFirstChild(root);

    if (element == null)
    {
        // not found
        return;
    }

    // great!  window found
    var window = element;

    // now look for a button with the text "Edit..."
    var buttonElement = window.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants,
        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Edit.."));
    if (buttonElement == null)
    {
        // not found
        return;
    }

    // great! now click the button
    var invokePattern = buttonElement.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern;
    invokePattern?.Invoke();
}
```

Important! The linked source of this code says the following:

```
var buttonElement = window.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children
```

But this does not work in the "Properties" window. It does not find "Edit..." in this level.
You have to search for it one level deeper:

```
var buttonElement = window.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants
```

Answer (score 1):

What I know, you need to use [EditSecurity function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/aclui/nf-aclui-editsecurity) from aclui.dll and implement [ISecurityInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/aclui/nn-aclui-isecurityinformation#methods) interface.

```
[DllImport("aclui.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern bool EditSecurity(IntPtr hwnd, ISecurityInformation psi);
```

Interface

```
[Guid("965FC360-16FF-11d0-91CB-00AA00BBB723")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface ISecurityInformation
{
    void GetObjectInformation([Out] out SI_OBJECT_INFO pObjectInfo);
    void GetSecurity([In] uint RequestedInformation, [Out] out IntPtr ppSecurityDescriptor, [In] bool fDefault);
    void SetSecurity([In] uint SecurityInformation, [In] IntPtr pSecurityDescriptor);
    void GetAccessRights([In] IntPtr pguidObjectType, [In] uint dwFlags, [Out] out IntPtr ppAccess, [Out] out int pcAccesses, [Out] out int piDefaultAccess);
    void MapGeneric([In] IntPtr pguidObjectType, [In] IntPtr pAceFlags, [In, Out] ref uint pMask);
    void GetInheritTypes([Out] out IntPtr ppInheritTypes, [Out] out int pcInheritTypes);
    void PropertySheetPageCallback([In] IntPtr hwnd, [In] uint uMsg, [In] uint uPage);
}
```

[SI_OBJECT_INFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/aclui/ns-aclui-si_object_info) structure

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SI_OBJECT_INFO
{
    public uint dwFlags;
    public IntPtr hInstance;
    public IntPtr pszServerName;
    public IntPtr pszObjectName;
    public IntPtr pszPageTitle;
    public Guid guidObjectType;
}
```

`SecurityInformation` class. Right now, I don't know how to implement all methods of `ISecurityInformation`.

```
public class SecurityInformation : ISecurityInformation
{
    SecurityInformation() 
    { 
    }

    void ISecurityInformation.GetObjectInformation(out SI_OBJECT_INFO pObjectInfo)
    {
        pObjectInfo = new SI_OBJECT_INFO()
        {
            // TODO
        };
    }

    void ISecurityInformation.GetSecurity(uint RequestedInformation, out IntPtr ppSecurityDescriptor, bool fDefault)
    {
        // TODO
    }

    void ISecurityInformation.SetSecurity(uint SecurityInformation, IntPtr pSecurityDescriptor)
    {
        // TODO
    }

    void ISecurityInformation.GetAccessRights(IntPtr pguidObjectType, uint dwFlags, out IntPtr ppAccess, out int pcAccesses, out int piDefaultAccess)
    {
        // TODO
    }

    void ISecurityInformation.MapGeneric(IntPtr pguidObjectType, IntPtr pAceFlags, ref uint pMask)
    {
        // TODO
    }

    void ISecurityInformation.GetInheritTypes(out IntPtr ppInheritTypes, out int pcInheritTypes)
    {
        // TODO
    }

    void ISecurityInformation.PropertySheetPageCallback(IntPtr hwnd, uint uMsg, uint uPage)
    {
        // TODO
    }
}
```